# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,2,3'

Tags: python

I want to get the maximum number between three values,but i got an error

```
def maxNumber(a,b,c):
    print('The maximum number is: {}'.format(max(a,b,c)))

a,b,c = int(input('Please Enter Three Numbers'))
maxNumber(a,b,c)
```

```
Please Enter Three Numbers1,2,3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5688feb4f653> in <module>
     2     print('The maximum number is: {}'.format(max(a,b,c)))
     3 
----> 4 x,y,z = int(input('Please Enter Three Numbers'))
     5 maxNumber(x,y,z)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,2,3'
```

Comment: You need to use `split()` to split the input and then convert each into a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to take multiple inputs in a single line you have to `split` the entered values.

```
x, y, z = input("Enter three values: ").split()
```

Your solution:

```
def maxNumber(a,b,c):
    print('The maximum number is: {}'.format(max(a,b,c)))

a,b,c = input('Please Enter Three Numbers').split()
maxNumber(a,b,c)
```

When asked to enter values, enter space-separated values or split accordingly.

Comment: it pop another error ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1) after entering the three values

Comment: It has 2 problems - first, you didnt converted the numbers to int - it means that '12' will be smaller than '2' which is a bug.... Second, you didnt determine the separator for the split method.

Comment: how did you enter the values, the values has to space-separated since default split() split by space. if you are entering comma-separated values use split(',')

Comment: you can cast the values to int individually or can refer to @theletz answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is a string of number separated by commas.
You have to convert the string to list of strings first (using split), 
then convert the string numbers to ints and pass to your function:

```
def maxNumber(a,b,c):
print('The maximum number is: {}'.format(max(a,b,c)))

string_input = input('Please Enter Three Numbers')
list_of_strings = string_input.split(',')
list_of_ints = [int(i) for i in list_of_strings]
maxNumber(list_of_ints)
```

Answer (score 0):

max( [int(input('Please Enter a Number ')) for i in range(3)] )